# Error sparkjava deploy on heroku

Tags: heroku, spark-java

Faced such error while deploying basic sparkjava webapp from official tutorial on heroku:

"Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.4.4:deploy (default-cli) on project myapp: Execution default-cli of goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.4.4:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.4.4:deploy: sun/misc/**BASE64Encoder**"

I tried to recreate the project many times, but it always fails.

Could it be related to JDK version 9 or some maven configuration issue? Ty in advance, sorry for unstructured error sample.

Listing of pom.xml is following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>

                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
                    <appName>spark-application</appName>
                    <processTypes>

                        <web>java -jar ./target/myapp-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you send you're maven file?

Comment: Added pom.xml file. It seems to be simple, but I'm not advanced in web-development and could do some mistakes.

Comment: Does the jar work locally?

Comment: Yes, it works fine through command prompt. But on "mvn heroku:deploy" it fails. Error log actually is bigger, should I post it? Thought that first part is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was really silly: version of maven-heroku-plugin was obsolete, after revising source folder and finding 2 versions (0.4.4 and 1.3.3) I've just changed version to 1.3.3 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I change de maven plugin version for 2.0.3

```
<groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.3</version>
```